# What caused the transverse "scarring" of the Atlantic Ocean floor

Tags: oceanic-crust

In Google Maps the floor of the Atlantic Ocean is shown as having much transverse "scarring". What are these crust formations? They're ~2,000 miles long. What caused them?

[image: Atlantic Ocean floor in Google Maps]

Comment: They are called "transform faults". See duplicate for more info.